# json white space syntax error due to array construct or something else?

Tags: json

Got the "syntaxError: JSON parse; unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 611 of the JSON data" error. While there are a lot of questions and answers about this and I see what is happening in my code, my question is:

Does this error originate with the construction of the array code here:

```
echo json_encode(array('html' => $html_string, 'cid' => $cid));
```

The input is:

```
  $html_string = ['<div class="myclass">'.$value-> Customer_FName.'</div><div class="myclass">'.$value-> Customer_LName.'</div>'];
   $cid[] = $value->id;
```

The output of the echo dumps as :

```
{"html":"<div class=\\\"myclass\\\">Bob<\/div><div class=\\\"myclass\\\">Smith<\/div>","cid":["44","45","46"]}0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try escaping your special characters. Example:

```
{
  "html": "<div class=\"flx2 waitlist-image waitlist-listing-img-pointer\">{$value-> Customer_FName}</div><div class=\"flx2 waitlist-image waitlist-listing-img-pointer\">{$value-> Customer_LName}</div>",
  "cid": [
    "44",
    "45",
    "46"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you the above is the output of the echo, not the html string. Here is the HTML string `$html_string .= '<div class="flx2 waitlist-image waitlist-listing-img-pointer">{$value-> Customer_FName}</div><div class="flx2 waitlist-image waitlist-listing-img-pointer">{$value-> Customer_LName}</div>';
       $cid[] = $value->id_In_Restaurant;`

Comment: Ah, you need to escape the quotes. Answer updated!

Comment: Thanks. The answer is a combo of the output and the input though. :/ I updated above since it is easier to see. Unless I escaped incorrectly, I am still getting my json error and the output doesnt seem right from what I have done. It doesnt seem to be running the for each properly for the string. It seems to only run once

Comment: Found it with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#. There is a "0" at the end of the darn thing due to a missing `die;` at the end of the loop after my echo.